# "they were getting called the n-word" is this correct?

Tags: passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs

I have the next sentence

> > They didn't change their content, they kept tweeting the same as usual, but suddenly, the white guys noticed **they were getting called** the n-word all the time and they were getting the worst kind of online abuse, whereas the black women all of a sudden noticed things got a lot more pleasant for them.

Is "they were getting called" correct or a author made a mistake and he should have used "they were being called"?

Comment: In US colloquial English *get* very often replaces *be* as the passive auxiliary.

Comment: It's not a "mistake". Using *get* instead of *be* in such contexts is probably more common in AmE than BrE, and to my mind it's slightly more "informal, colloquial", but essentially it's "normal usage".

Comment: I'd call it common but wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In formal writing, this would be wrong and it should be "being called" or simple "were called".

In informal writing, this wouldn't necessarily be wrong: "getting" replacing "being" is, as mentioned in a comment on the question, a reasonably common colloquial usage in the US: or at least in certain areas in the US.

In British English it would almost always be wrong unless being deliberately used as slang.